# Amazon DynamoDB - Is there a way to not specify each AttributeName?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb

Reading the DynamoDB docs, it seems that there is no way to not list out each attribute name/value when inserting data.

For example, to insert a user I'd need to do this:

```
var putRequest = new PutItemRequest
    {
        TableName = UsersTableName,
        Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
            {
                {"HashId", new AttributeValue() { S = user.Id.ToString() }},
                {"RangeId", new AttributeValue() { S = user.Email }},
                {"CreatedUtc", new AttributeValue() { S = user.CreatedUtc.ToString() }},
                {"DeactivatedUtc", new AttributeValue() { S = user.DeactivatedUtc.ToString() }},
                {"Timezone", new AttributeValue() { S = "US Eastern Standard Time" }},
            }
    };

var result = DbClient.PutItem(putRequest);
```

I like the RavenDb model of accepting any POCO and figuring out the "attribute" names on it's own, based on the class' public field names.

My question is: Do I need to do this?  Is there away to write the data just by passing the object?

If not I am going to write something that will: I will use reflection to figure out the names and types and generate the `PutItemRequest.Item` dictionary based on that.  I'd rather not if I don't have to.

As always, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Amazon already has exactly what I was looking for: The [.NET Object Persistence Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html)

This takes care of serializing your objects for you - wonderful!

Answer (score 2):

On every `putItem` request you should specify **all** attributes you want to store. If you miss some of them - their values will be deleted from DynamoDB. And there is no workaround at the moment. In order to change one attribute you should `getItem` first, change it in memory and `putItem` it back to DynamoDB.

Comment: I guess I could use the straight HTTP method, and use a JSON deserializer, correct?  Alternatively, I may end up writing some small library to create the attribute dictionary using reflection.  If I do, I will paste the link here.